# ¿Qué significa & antes de una variable?

Tags: php

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
    $valor = $valor * 2;
}
// $array ahora es array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($valor); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento
```

Lo anterior lo encontré en la documentación de php sobre cómo hacer un `foreach` y pone: `&$valor`, pero no entiendo para qué sirve el `&` antes de la variable

Alguien puede decirme qué significa?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

De la documentación en http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php

> Para poder modificar directamente los elementos del array dentro de bucle, se ha de anteponer & a $valor. En este caso el valor será asignado por referencia.

```
<?php
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
    $valor = $valor * 2;
}
// $array ahora es array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($valor); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento
?>
```

---

Para responder a tu comentario. `&` indica un valor por referencia (algo similar a un puntero en otros lenguajes.

[Objetos y referencias](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.references.php):

```
$a = new Foo; // $a es un puntero a un objeto Foo 0
$b = $a; // $b es un puntero a un objeto Foo 0, sin embargo, $b es una copia de $a
$c = &$a; // $c y $a son ahora referencias de un puntero que apunta al objeto Foo 0
```

Comment: Pero en el contexto tiene algún significado o sólo es un operador que se asignó para dar la funcionalidad? tiene uso fuera de foreach?

Comment: Tiene uso donde quieras dárselo, si lo pones como parámetro de entrada en una función, al pasar esa variable a la función y modificarlo dentro de esta, también se modificará fuera, sin necesidad de haber retornado ningún valor en la función.